# Сервер прислал объект типа 'Buffer'. Как сделать из него ссылку на изображение?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blob, buffer

[image: скриншот из инструментов разработчика Chrome]

Сервер присылает мне ответ где помимо прочих данных под ключом 'image' лежит объект с type: 'Buffer', это должно быть изображение.
Под ключом data лежит массив с числами.

Пытался получить ссылку.

```
const src = useMemo(() => {
    const imgBlob = new Blob(image?.data || [], { type: 'image/jpg' });
    return URL.createObjectURL(imgBlob);
  }, [image]);
```

Но по полученной ссылке увы ничего не отображается. Что я могу со стороны фронтэнда сделать? Или может изменения нужны на бекенде?

Comment: сервер может прислать не буфер, а ссылку на файл? если может - лучше сделать так. если не может то на серверной стороне закодировать буфер в base64 и на клиентской стороне работать с ним сразу же как Data URL

Answer (score -1):

Внесли изменения на бекенде чтобы он превращал этот объект в строку base64, теперь всё работает.
Насколько я понял на фронтенде нет инструментов для работы с этим форматом.